# Make a .vbs to list contents of a directory and pass all that as an argument to a program

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, md5, command-line-arguments

**I'm trying to make a VBScript files to pass arguments to an MD5Checker Tool.** And the arguments are the directory and sub-directory listings of a certain directory (e.g. "C:\Stuff").

Arguments passed like: Md5Checker.exe "file1.exe" "More Stuff\files2.exe"

I need an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky) method to run an external command like that. The method takes a string with the full command line (command and arguments), executes it, and returns the exit code of the executed program.

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

arg1 = "file1.exe"
arg2 = "More Stuff\files2.exe"

cmd = "Md5Checker.exe " & qq(arg1) & " " & qq(arg2)
returnCode = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run cmd, 0, True
```

The function `qq()` is for simplifying putting double quotes around arguments a little.